# Python IP Address Module

Tags: python, module, pip, ip-address

I was hoping I could get some assistance with my python module installations, specifically around the ipaddress module.  This issue is driving me crazy...

In short, I wrote a python3 script on my Windows machine that utilises the ipaddress module.  This works absolutely fine.

I've copied this to the Linux box (Ubuntu 18.04) that I want to run it on, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
File "/opt/netbox-2.6.7/netbox/reports/address-parents.py", line 82, in test_aci_endpoints
  if endpoint.subnet_of(summary):
AttributeError: 'IPv4Network' object has no attribute 'subnet_of'
```

When I query the module, I get the following:

```
nbxla01lv:/opt/netbox/netbox$ pip3 show ipaddress
Name: ipaddress
Version: 1.0.23
Summary: IPv4/IPv6 manipulation library
Home-page: https://github.com/phihag/ipaddress
Author: Philipp Hagemeister
Author-email: phihag@phihag.de
License: Python Software Foundation License
Location: /home/andy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

This is slightly confusing to me as looking at that homepage for the module, it seems to be a port of the 3.3+ ipaddress module for python 2.7.  Regardless, version 1.0.23 is the latest release and contains the function 'subnet_of'.

Also, if I look to the actual code itself in /home/andy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipaddress.py, I can see the actual function in the code:

```
nbxla01lv:/home/andy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages$ cat ipaddress.py | grep subnet_of
        if not other.subnet_of(self):
            if other.subnet_of(s1):
            elif other.subnet_of(s2):
    def _is_subnet_of(a, b):
    def subnet_of(self, other):
        return self._is_subnet_of(self, other)
        return self._is_subnet_of(other, self)
```

I'm sure this is something simple, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit - sample code**

```
# Query APIC for all endpoint IPs. 
endpointQuery = '/api/node/class/fvIp.json'
resp = requests.get(aciBaseURL + endpointQuery, cookies=cookie, verify=False).json()

ipAddressCount = int(resp["totalCount"])
aciIPs = []
counter = 0
summary = ipaddress.ip_network(inputSummary)

while counter < ipAddressCount:
    endpoint = ipaddress.ip_network(resp['imdata'][counter]["fvIp"]["attributes"]["addr"])
    if endpoint.subnet_of(summary):
        aciIPs.append(str(endpoint))
    counter+=1
```

Comment: A) Could you write a short bit of code to reproduce the problem? B) Have you considered using pipenv or similar so that you get exactly the same versions of packages on both installs?

Comment: I've edited my original post with the sample code, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ipaddress` module is part of the standard library so I guess you're importing that version.

You can also verify which module you're actually importing

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.__file__
'/Users/rickard/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/ipaddress.py'
```

Most likely the `subnet_of` method is missing from the `ipaddress` module in your current installation of Python (looks like 3.6)

Comment: Okay, looks like we're getting somewhere...

`>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.6/ipaddress.py'`

Which I just checked, and doesn't contain the 'subnet_of' method.

So next question, how am I best fixing this?  Upgrading python on the Ubuntu box?

Comment: I would recommend upgrading Python.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, just wanted to say that the upgrade to python 3.7 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to (or can't) upgrade Python, you can follow the concepts in [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Rather than importing via:

```
import ipaddress
```

you can choose a different version using:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "./virtualenvs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipaddress.py")
ipaddress = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(ipaddress)
```

Just change the path to reflect the correct module location.